# Symfony 2 entity field attributes

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, symfony-forms

I have in my form an entity field. This field looks like this:

```
->add('user', 'entity',array(
                                'class' => 'Elearning\SiteBundle\Entity\User',
                                'property' => 'name',
                                'multiple' => true,
                                'expanded' => true,
                                'required' => true,
                                'label' => 'Użytkownicy ',
                                'attr' => array('class' => 'userFiledCollection'), // this not working. It set class to parent div. I want to have this class in checkboxes.
                                'query_builder' =>function(EntityRepository $er) {
                                                     return $er
                                                        ->createQueryBuilder('u')
                                                        ->where('u.isActive = 1');
                                                      },
                        )
                    )
```

All i want to do is to set an class attribute to all checkboxes rendered by this filed. How can i do this?

Comment: The same class to all checkboxes? Do you really need to? Rule of thumb with CSS: If you give all elements the same class, then you are doing something wrong. For example, you can style them using a descendant selector: `.userFiledCollection input[type=checkbox] { ... }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no build-in solutions. See [this issue](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/3836).

Possible solution - use [Form theming](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#form-theming):

```
{% form_theme form _self %}

{% block checkbox_widget %}
    {% spaceless %}
        {% set attr = attr|merge({'class': 'userFiledCollection'}) %}
        <input type="checkbox" {{ block('widget_attributes') }}{% if value is defined %} value="{{ value }}"{% endif %}{% if checked %} checked="checked"{% endif %} />
    {% endspaceless %}
{% endblock checkbox_widget %}

{% block body %}
    {{ form(form) }}
{% endblock %}
```